# I want to deny Travis CI access to an organization

Tags: github, travis-ci

I want to use Travis CI for personal projects, I would like to know if it is possible to prevent Travis CI to have access to an organization as a member and not an administrator.

Comment: Have you ever found out about it?

Comment: Yeah, even I'm also wondering the same.

Comment: You just don't invite the organization. Easy as that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Github account for yourself it is a personal account. That account can be a member or owner of any number of Github organizations.

If you are just trying to add Travis CI so that it has access to your personal repositories but not to the organizations you administer, you can do so easily.

When you sign in to the Travis CI website with your personal Github account for the first time, it asks you to "authorize Travis CI":

- This page has an "organizations and teams" section that defaults to read-only (it can see what repositories etc your orgs have but cannot take any actions on them)
- This page also has an "Organization Access" section at the bottom with a list of each Github organization you are a member of. As long as you do not click "request" or "grant" on any of those, your orgs will not yield any control to Travis CI.